# Select any element in array

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit, ios9

I am developing a game and it consists in a couple arrows moving in the scene. I've set some collisions and i need to remove the arrow that colides with a barrier. What i've set is pretty simple and functional, but only with one arrow, because it is element [0] of the array, clearly if another one (not the [0]) touches the barrier, it would not be removed from parent. Is there any way i can use to delegate a collision to all elements in spite of needing to manually atribute the arrays element each number?

```
  // 3. react to the contact between the two nodes
        if firstBody.categoryBitMask == barrier?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask &&
            secondBody.categoryBitMask == arrows[0].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask {
                // Player & barrier

                gameOver(false)
        }  else if firstBody.categoryBitMask == goal?.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask && secondBody.categoryBitMask == arrows[0].physicsBody?.categoryBitMask {
            // Player & Goal

            arrows[0].removeFromParent()
//            gameOver(true)
```

Thanks!

:)

Answer (score 1):

Then you initialize your `arrow` and `goal` you should give them `categoryBitMask`s

```
arrow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0x1 << 0
goal.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0x1 << 1
barrie.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0x1 << 2
```

Also i recommend you to create `Constants.swift` file and store your constants there.
`Constants.swift`:

```
let kCategoryArrow: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let kCategoryGoal: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
let kCategoryBarrie: UInt32 = 0x1 << 2
```

Then you can give `categoryBitMask`s like this (then you initialize them)

```
arrow.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = kCategoryArrow
goal.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = kCategoryGoal
barrier.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = kCategoryBarrier
```

And the last thing check for contact:

```
    /* Arrow vs Barrier */

    if bodyA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == kCategoryArrow && bodyB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == kCategoryBarrier {
        gameOver(false)
    } else if bodyA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == kCategoryBarrier && bodyB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == kCategoryBullet {
        gameOver(false)
    }

    /* Arrow vs Goal */

    if bodyA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == kCategoryArrow && bodyB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == kCategoryGoal {
        bodyA.node.removeFromParent()  
    } else if bodyA.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == kCategoryGoal && bodyB.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask == kCategoryBullet {
        bodyB.node.removeFromParent()
    }
```

Comment: I've initialized all the `categoryBitMask`. The problem is that each arrow should disapear when colliding, but they are located inside an array. I need a solution that can remove only the contacting one and not all of them.

Comment: @AlessandroNardinelli This solution is removing your arrows wich contacted with your goall. You do not even need an array.